# Draggable items for mobile with best performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, mobile, polymer

I need Draggable list for mobile with best performance
I use some jQuety plugin but not enough performance
Please tell me a javascript lib for dragging with high performance
I prefer polymer or react canvas way
Thank you

Comment: why i have -1 point ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [interactjs](http://interactjs.io/). It is the best performance I ever saw!

```js
// Target elements with the "draggable" class
interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
    // Enable inertial throwing
    inertia: true,
    // Keep the element within the area of it's parent
    restrict: {
      restriction: "parent",
      endOnly: true,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    },

    // Call this function on every dragmove event
    onmove: dragMoveListener,
    // Call this function on every dragend event
    onend: function (event) {
      var textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

      textEl && (textEl.textContent =
        'moved a distance of '
        + (Math.sqrt(event.dx * event.dx +
                     event.dy * event.dy)|0) + 'px');
    }
  });

  function dragMoveListener (event) {
    var target = event.target,
        // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
        x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
        y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    // Translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
    target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // Update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }

  // This is used later in the resizing demo
  window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;
```

```css
#drag-1, #drag-2 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 6.5em;
  margin: 10%;

  background-color: #29e;
  color: white;

  border-radius: 0.75em;
  padding: 4%;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
          transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

#drag-me::before {
  content: "#" attr(id);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.4/interact.min.js"></script>

<div id="drag-1" class="draggable">
  <p> You can drag one element </p>
</div>
<div id="drag-2" class="draggable">
    <p> with each pointer </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `iron-list` element might be of use to you. You can download it and see the documentation for it [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list).

Comment: I need draggable items, change item position

Answer (score 1):

For better performance on mobile, change translate to translate3d and add a third argument of 0:

```
'translate3d(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px, 0)';
```